# Joomla K2 meta property="og:description" Hacked

Tags: joomla, meta, k2

We use Joomla and K2 for our website.  On this page [website](http://www.clubdevo.com/index.php/news) in the  the meta property="og:description" has been hacked and it shows this content="buy zolpidem us zolpidem online...  And wo when we post to Facebook we get this text in the description.

Any idea where to look for this text and delete it?  I have searched and found the K2 file that pulls the text.  I just dont know where the text lives.

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 0):

I just had this happen with Wordpress... in my case deleting and reinstalling the Facebook plugin fixed this particular issue.  The strange thing was the FB plugin wasn't modified in any way.

The larger issue was the site had been hacked - which in your case is almost certainly true as well.  I'm not familiar with Joomla, but scan the rest of your files/folders for malware or suspicious code (and your site structure for invisible files and folders (beginning with a '.'), possibly reinstall your files, check your htaccess file to make sure nothing has been added, check the registered users on the site -- any suspicious admins? -- and change your passwords.

In other words, this is a symptom of a greater problem, and not the problem itself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did.  I had the hosting copy run a grep to search on my web data for the string containing the malicious text.

Once we found the files I used clean PHP files from another Joomla instal to overwrite the hacked files.

The hacked PHP file was pulling a string of malicious text from a text file named value(s)

I then backed-up the website and installed another layer of security called Admin Tools. The Pro version cost money but could be used on as any websites as I needed.